# Sending many json objects with one object json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-restful-framework and django 1.5

I having trouble to POST. Hard to explain so let start with example.

**Models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='task')
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('task_title')

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = TaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('project_name', 'project_description', 'task')
```

When I to this, the viewsets.ModelViewSet in django-rest-framework displays with text field for task :
[image]

But I it gives me error when posting without filling in the task field :

```
add() argument after * must be a sequence, not NoneType
```

Is there a nice way to connect Project to task so I can create Project without task, and create as many tasks as I want inside project? Also /project and /task display the same form though there are different fields in the model.

I'm using the django-rest-framework default view to test the api for now.

p.s I'm trying to write this as clear as possible, please let me know if I'm missing something for better help.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Django REST](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html) page, it says:

```
Note that nested relationships are currently read-only.
```

"Read Only" would make posting a little difficult ;)

Comment: Someone must have hack for this? or an idea for me how i can get passed this for the time being. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hacked through my problem by using "[HyperlinkedRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)" just have to GET every link to retrieve the information.